# Why will this code not print the list of items? I know its to do with return

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, return

I know it should return a value to the main function but do not know how to output the list without doing it in the main function.

I want to be able to call the menu function and it print the list of items to the screen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int menu;
    return 0;
};

int Menu (const char *Items[3], int Price [], int NoItems ) 
{
    int i;
    //assigning values to arrays
    Items[1] = "lamp";
    Items[2] = "Toothbrush";
    Items[3] = "Battery";

    Price[1] = 4.5;
    Price[2] = 3.68;
    Price[3] = 0.99;

    for(i=1; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("1) %s: %d\n",Items[i], Price[i]);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to call `Menu` function from `main`

Comment: Also a good idea to format the code so that it is readable

Comment: @Stringyy - Just formatted the code (rather VS did it for me)

Comment: Your indexes should be 0-2, not 1-3!!!

Comment: In main, function declaration is wrong. In menu, the arguments are useless, and as @barak said, the index should be started from 0 not 1.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you aren't getting any output...

The compiler makes the resulting executable so that it starts with `main`. Since `main` does not call the function with your output, `Menu`, it doesn't get called at all.

It appears from that you have `Menu` after `main` that you are trying to have it execute last. To do this, you could simply have it as the last call in `main`, or you could use `atexit(Menu);` to have it called upon exit (even if the program is terminated early, such as with a call to `exit`).

Also the people in the comments of your post are right - the indices (`[...]`) don't make much sense. They are technically valid but depending on your usage you may get a memory access violation due to buffer overflow (trying to access memory beyond what is allocated for the array will give you junk data or, more likely, will crash your application entirely, immediately if the OS or hardware detects that the program is trying to use memory it doesn't own, or later on if you broke the stack by writing something to it).

You can put the variable initializer `int i = 0;` in the `for` loop itself.

You are using `int`s for the `Price` values, but assigning them non-integers. They will be truncated (made into whole numbers) in this case. Instead, I recommend you use `float`s which retain the more precise values you put in them.

It's not necessary to return a value from `Menu` unless it provides something not constant. Since it's just returning `0`, you are wasting 4 bytes of memory to have something that always equals `0`.

Since `Menu` is declared after `main`, in which it is called, you must either **1.** Provide a *function prototype* (which I have demonstrated below) or **2.** Move the function itself to before any places where it is called.

I assume that where you have `"1)"` in your output you mean to show the number of each item in the list. If you want this to change as you step through your list, you need to not always have it `"1)"` but rather use an escape character and provide a variable.

---

To put this all together...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Menu (const char**, float*); // Prototype
int main()
{
    const char* Items [3];
    float Price [3];
    Menu(Items,Price);
    return 0;
};
void Menu (const char *Items [3], float Price [3]) 
{
    Items[0] = "Lamp";
    Items[1] = "Toothbrush";
    Items[2] = "Battery";
    Price[0] = 4.5;
    Price[1] = 3.68;
    Price[2] = 0.99;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%d) %s: %f\n", i + 1, Items[i], Price[i]);
};
```